# XSL-FO: Getting System.SystemException: Unknown formatting object ^h2 with disable-output-escaping="yes"

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm using [Fonet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fonet/#readme-body-tab) to render XSL to PDF.
In my .xslt I have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

In my C# I have the method to crate the PDF memory stream from the XML memory stream:

```
private static MemoryStream Xml2Pdf(MemoryStream msTransform)
    {
        FonetDriver d = FonetDriver.Make();
        msTransform.Position = 0;
        MemoryStream msOut = new MemoryStream();
        d.Render(msTransform, msOut);
        return msOut;
    }
```

The value of Text is:

```
<h2><strong><span style="color:#0e8a16;">Text 1</span></strong></h2><h2 style="text-align:center"><em><span style="color:#fef2c0;"><span style="background-color:#0052cc;">Text 2</span></span></em></h2><h4 style="text-align:right"><u>Text 3</u></h4>
```

**d.Render** throws *System.SystemException: Unknown formatting object ^h2*

If I use a *Text* without HTML everything works fine.

And I don't have any clue how to fix it

Comment: You have HTML, not xml (posting is tagged with xml).  Your data is an array.  Usually XML has only one root tag.  You file is an array of h2.

Comment: I guess that under the hood XSL-FO is used i.e. using a cross-compiled Apache FOP version converting XSL-FO to PDF. Your attempt to use `disable-output-escaping` within your pipeline seems to pass the embedded HTML elements to the FOP rendering engine which rightly complains that the input is not any XSL-FO element. Thus, if you want to have your embedded HTML being rendered in PDF you need some way to transform the HTML to XSL-FO, custom XSLT can do that.